# In R, in vegan function simper(), why do I get an error message stating that "...length of 'dimnames' [1] not equal to array extent"

Tags: r, vegan

I am trying to pass the `dune` dataset and one column of the `dune.env` dataset to function `vegan::simper()`, but am consistently being shown an error message. This error message is shown even when I run code copied directly from the `simper()` help panel, which differs slighlty from my code shown below.

```
> library(vegan)
> data("dune"); data("dune.env")
> simper(dune,dune.env$Moisture)
Error in array(r, dim = d, dimnames = if (!(is.null(n1 <- names(x[[1L]])) &  : 
  length of 'dimnames' [1] not equal to array extent
```

I tried converting `dune.env$Moisture` into a `data.frame`, to more closely match the input requirements of other vegan functions such as `cca()`, but continue receive the same error.

```
> (dune_moisture <- data.frame("dune_moisture" = dune.env$Moisture))
   dune_moisture
1              1
2              1
3              2
4              2
5              1
6              1
7              1
8              5
9              4
10             2
11             1
12             4
13             5
14             5
15             5
16             5
17             2
18             1
19             5
20             5
> simper(dune,dune_moisture)
Error in array(r, dim = d, dimnames = if (!(is.null(n1 <- names(x[[1L]])) &  : 
  length of 'dimnames' [1] not equal to array extent
```

How do I pass data to `vegan::simper()`?

Comment: I cannot replicate your issue, `simper(dune,dune.env$Moisture)` works fine. Are your versions of R and package vegan up to date?

Comment: I'm using R version 4.2.1, which I believe is the current version.

Comment: Yes. Try data(dune); data(dune.env) without quotation marks and then `simper(dune,dune.env$Moisture)`.

Comment: I was able to successfully run this code on another computer. Maybe there is a vegan dependency that I did not load to library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar problem has been reported earlier and fixed in the latest CRAN release (2.6-4) of **vegan**. The problem emerges when **proxy** package is loaded simultaneously with **vegan**. **proxy** changes the way how standard **R** distance structures are handled, and this interferes dealing with distances within `simper`. This is discussed in https://github.com/vegandevs/vegan/issues/528, and indeed fixed in the latest **vegan** release (2.6-4). If you cannot get the latest **vegan** release, unload **proxy** and things should work.